# Modify content before sending to browser

Tags: 8

I want to modify all the `<a href src` of the Drupal content before it's sent to the browser. So far I have tried the following.

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) : void
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        // Replacement for link headers for domains for Chinese vs. Other Languages.
        $headers = $response->headers;
        $links = $headers->get('link','',false);
        $links = str_replace($this->domain_patterns, $this->domain_replacements, $links);
        $headers->remove('link');
        $headers->set('link',$links, false);
        // Replacement for h2->h1 when neccesary and domains for Chinese vs. other languages in content.
        echo $html = $response->getContent();
```

But I don't get anything to be return in `$html`.

Comment: You might want to use preprocess hooks to read and replace the content. See here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x for some detail. I'm not sure where you're planning on looking for these links but for example if you were looking for them in node fields you could do a hook_preprocess_field and replace what you need from inside there.

Comment: I don't think your code does what you are intending. The Symfony Response headers represent a Symfony ResponseHeadersBag object, which represent HTTP Headers and not HTML at all.